# Is it possible to use values from my Azure Key Vault in a Specflow feature file's example table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, specflow, gherkin

My Feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: Login

Scenario Outline: a <role> User Logs In
    Given an admin user navigates to the home page
    And logs out if they are already logged in
    When <role> User enters login credentials of <username> & <password>
    Then they are logged in successfully
    And presented with <role> UI

    Examples:
        | role             | username             | password         |
        | User1            | {U1keyVaultUsername} | {U1keyVaultPass} |
```

The LogIn credentials for the users are stored in an Azure KeyVault. I would like to populate the login credentials with the values from the KeyVault

```
[When(@"(.*) User enters login credentials of (.*) & (.*)")]
public void WhenUserEntersLoginCredentials(String role, String username, String password)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entering Username/Email...");
    this._driver.FindElement(this._userNameTextField).SendKeys(username);
            
    //Find element Id of "password" textbox & enter password
    Console.WriteLine("Entering Password...");
    _driver.FindElement(this._passwordTextField).SendKeys(password);

    Console.WriteLine("Clicking Sign In...");
    _driver.FindElement(this._submitLoginBtn).Click(); 
}
```

Comment: I think you can access those values as environment variables, but I don't remember. Regardless, if you are getting these values from the Azure Key Vault, I wouldn't even put that information in the scenario. The step could simply be `When <role> User logs in`. The step definition could retrieve that value, rather than passing that value in from the step itself. As a general rule, do not put real passwords in your feature files. They are plain text, and not secure.

Comment: The [Microsoft Quickstart - Azure Key Vault secrets client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net) documentation is a good place to start. That is part of the solution.

Comment: Thank You, @GregBurghardt. That's the approach I ended up taking